# Centos 8, is there simple way to apply network settings?

Tags: centos, linux-networking

using Centos as my favorite linux server OS. In 7 version to apply network settings simply used:

```
systemctl restart network
```

but in 8 version service network was removed.. i use:

```
nmcli networking off && nmcli networking on
```

instead. Restarting NetworkManager.service seems to not applying settings.
maybe i dont know about simplier way, point me please.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you have changed. Normally you can just restart whichever interface or connection you have reconfigured.

For example:

```
nmcli c down enp4s0 && nmcli c up enp4s0
```

Comment: that answer is in the question, and it is not simple.. appearently where is nothing simplier.